# how to create a subclass UIViewController by passing class name to a method?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 4 subclass UIViewController, named AViewController,BViewController,CViewController,DViewController.

now in a toolbar, click A, content view show AViewController's view, ...etc.

I am a kind of lazy man, hate writing 4 times "alloc]initwithnibname" codes, so I wrote following code to create them in code.

```
- (void)addChildView:(UIViewController *)childViewController className:(NSString *)viewClassName{
if (childViewController != nil) {
    // add view
    [self.contentView addSubview:childViewController.view];
}else
{
    // init.
    Class v = NSClassFromString(viewClassName);
    UIViewController *childViewControllerNew = nil;
    childViewControllerNew = [[v alloc] initWithNibName:viewClassName bundle:nil];
    [self.contentView addSubview:childViewController.view];
}}
```

But this won't create any ViewController, always return nil when debugging.

Could you tell me what is the problem? Can I created subclass UIViewController by this approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it nil after creation, or you're just not retaining it so its destroyed at the end of the method?

Comment: not nil. I will try retain it. thx.

Comment: oh, my fault! I am too careless. [self.contentView addSubview:childViewController.view] should be [self.contentView addSubview:childviewControllerNew.view]. Sorry for your time.

Comment: That change alone still doesn't retain the controller, just the view...

Comment: yes, that's the problem...working on how to retain the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a view controller, but then you aren't doing anything with it. There are 2 issues:

1. A typo means you're setting the wrong view (`[self.contentView addSubview:childViewController.view];`)
2. You aren't retaining `childViewControllerNew`

You should change the last block of code to something like:

```
Class v = NSClassFromString(viewClassName);
UIViewController *childViewControllerNew = nil;
childViewControllerNew = [[v alloc] initWithNibName:viewClassName bundle:nil];
[self.contentView addSubview:childViewControllerNew.view];

[self addChildViewController:childViewControllerNew];
```

Comment: I passed self.viewControllerA as parameter "childViewController" in method addChildView, and add childViewController = childViewControllerNew in code. but seems not work. the method seems cannot find the parameter acutally is a property defined (nonatomic, strong). :( possibly writing init controller codes one by one is safer and quicker. but at least the question make me understand memory management and ARC more.

Comment: finally solve this by traditional way. drop addChildView method, and write viewController init code one by one. This time view controllers are retained.

Answer (score 1):

if your are really lazy you can declare enum values like

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, VC) {
VCa,
VCb,
VCc,
VCd
};
```

and then in your do

```
- (void)addChildView:(UIViewController *)childViewController className:(VC)typeOfVC {
switch(typeOfVC)
      case VCa: ViewControllerA *vc = [ViewControllerA alloc] initwithNibName@"YourNibName"]
[self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
case: VCb : same with B 
etc
etc
}
```

also, you can use these cases in other classes to make a difference between the ViewControllers...